# Primefaces DataTable in Second tab not displaying data

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, tabview

I have a primefaces page containing 2 tabs.  Both tabs has its own data Table.  When finish querying data, dataTable in the first tab displays queried data fine but the second tab does not (please refer to the picture.)
here is my xhtml file code

```
<code>
<h:body>`enter code here`
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <p:menubar>
            <p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="ui-icon-close"   ajax="false" immediate="true"  action="#{logoutManagedBean.logout}" />
        </p:menubar>
        <p:growl id="growlExtractTimesheet" sticky="false" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
        <h:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px; border:none; border-style: none; border-width: 0px;" columns="7" >  
            <p:outputLabel for="fromDateCalendar" value='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From '  />
            <p:calendar id='fromDateCalendar' 
                value="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.fromDate}"  
                binding="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.fromDateCalendar}"
                pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
                required="true"
                requiredMessage="From Date Required" 
                valueChangeListener="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.determineExtractButtonDisability}" >
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" partialSubmit="fromDateCalendar" update="extractTimesheetButton" />
            </p:calendar>
            <p:outputLabel for="toDateCalendar" value='To ' />
            <p:calendar id='toDateCalendar' 
                value="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.toDate}" 
                binding="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.toDateCalendar}" 
                pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
                required="true"
                requiredMessage="To Date Required" 
                valueChangeListener="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.determineExtractButtonDisability}" >
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" partialSubmit="toDateCalendar" update="extractTimesheetButton" />
            </p:calendar>
            <p:commandButton id='extractTimesheetButton' 
                actionListener  ="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.extractTimesheetData}" 
                binding ="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.extractTimesheetCommandButton}"
                update='myForm:tabview:detailDataTable myForm:tabview:summaryDataTable myForm:downloadExcelsButton' 
                ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-calculator"    >
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton id="downloadExcelsButton"   ajax="false" actionListener="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.downloadExcelFile}" 
                binding="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.downloadExcelsCommandButton}" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" disabled="true"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:tabView id='tabview' cache="false">
            <p:tab title="Detail Data" id='detailTab'>
                <p:dataTable id='detailDataTable' var="detailData" paginatorPosition="top"
                    value="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.detailDatas}" paginator="true" 
                    rows="100"  rowsPerPageTemplate="100,200,500,1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000" lazy='true' 
                    currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} "
                    scrollable="true"   scrollHeight="350"
                    liveResize="true"   draggableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true"
                    selectionMode="multiple" selection="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.selectedDetailDatas}" rowKey="#{detailData.id}" >
                    <p:column headerText="Employee ID" width="80">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.employeeId}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Employee Name Lastname" width="200">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.employeeName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Cost Center" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.costCenter}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="WBS Code" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.wbsCode}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="WBS Name" width="300">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.wbsName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Project Code" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.projectCode}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Project Name" width="300">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.projectName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Activity" width="300">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.activity}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Task" width="300">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.task}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Role" width="150">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.role}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Timesheet Date" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.timesheetDate}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Total Working Hours" width="150">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.totalWorkingHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Utilized" width="50">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.utilized}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Billable" width="50">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.billable}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="OT" width="50">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.ot}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="On Time" width="80">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.onTime}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Status" width="80">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.status}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Remark" width="500">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detailData.remark}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Summary Data" id='summaryTab'>
                <p:dataTable id='summaryDataTable' var="summaryData" paginatorPosition="top"
                    value="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.summaryDatas}" paginator="true" 
                    rows="50"  rowsPerPageTemplate="50, 100, 200" lazy='true' 
                    currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} "
                    scrollable="true"  scrollHeight="350" 
                    liveResize="true"   draggableColumns="true"    resizableColumns="true"
                    selectionMode="multiple" selection="#{dataProcessingManagedBean.selectedSummaryDatas}" rowKey="#{summaryData.id}" >
                    <p:column headerText="Employee ID" width="80">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.employeeId}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Employee Name Lastname" width="200">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.employeeName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Normal Billable hour(s)" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.normalBillableHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Normal Non-Billable hour(s)" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.normalNonBillableHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Total Normal hours(s)" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.totalNormalHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="OT Billable hour(s)" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.otBillableHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="OT Non-Billable hour(s)" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.otNonBillableHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Total OT hour(s)" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.totalOTHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Total hour(s)" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{summaryData.totalHours}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
        <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" onerror="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>
        <p:dialog id="waitDialog" widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax_wait.gif"  />
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and this is the result.[image: the dataTable in the first (default) tab is working fine.]

[image: but the dataTable in the second tab does not display the result set even we know the result set is there as we can see the number of rows displayed.]

if anyone has come across this problem and solved it. please help  Thank you.

Comment: First I would use double quotation marks for all attributes. Not sure why the 2nd dataTable is not dispayed, but I had also some strange behaviour with `p:tabView` (maybe it depends what you put inside it). Therefore mostly I use `p:TabView` only as trigger. In your case the `p:tabs` would be empty and a ajax listener `tabChange` would be added to `p:tabView.` The dataTables are conditionally rendered then depends on your selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem by putting attribute dynamic='true' for tabView component.